# Azure Storage CDN Connection String

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I've created an Azure Storage account and can upload and download files using a connection string like below in C#:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXX;AccountKey=YYY;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```

I've added CDN to this account, and I have the endpoint hostname:

```
https://zzz.azureedge.net
```

How can I modify the connection string so that content is downloaded using the CDN instead of, I guess, directly from the storage account based where-ever I set it up (in my case, the UK)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a different string for that in a format:

```
http://<EndpointName>.azureedge.net/<myPublicContainer>/<BlobName>
```

(see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn) for details).

Reason for that is that non-read operations must go to your central location and then they get propagated to CDNs according to refresh policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom url for the various types of storage endpoints.
For example:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXX;AccountKey=YYY;BlobEndpoint=https://zzz.azureedge.net
```

You can use this to use a custom domain as well.

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string).